# Laravel Log Truncation

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-artisan, illuminate-container

I'm getting an error back on an API scraping service I've setup due to the API source changing some element on their end. I've been working my way through trying to sort it all out, but I'm stuck on a particular object conversion error. When I try to look in the logs at what it's choking on, the relevant data is getting truncated. Any idea how to undo that? Here is my stack trace:

```
[2016-02-26 17:47:55] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string' in /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php:671
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(4096, 'Object of class...', '/var/www/myapp....', 671, Array)
#1 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(671): preg_replace('/\?/', 'Object', 'insert into `pr...', 1)
#2 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.php(56): str_replace_array('\?', Array, 'insert into `pr...')
#3 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.php(39): Illuminate\Database\QueryException->formatMessage('insert into `pr...', Array, Object(ErrorException))
#4 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(633): Illuminate\Database\QueryException->__construct('insert into `pr...', Array, Object(ErrorException))
#5 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(591): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `pr...', Array, Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(381): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('insert into `pr...', Array, Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(337): Illuminate\Database\Connection->statement('insert into `pr...', Array)
#8 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php(32): Illuminate\Database\Connection->insert('insert into `pr...', Array)
#9 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1735): Illuminate\Database\Query\Processors\Processor->processInsertGetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder), 'insert into `pr...', Array, 'id')
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->insertGetId(Array, 'id')
#11 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(940): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1584): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('insertGetId', Array)
#13 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1584): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->insertGetId(Array, 'id')
#14 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1555): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->insertAndSetId(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Array)
#15 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1461): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->performInsert(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), Array)
#16 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/app/RevelModel.php(87): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
#17 [internal function]: App\RevelModel::scrapData(Array)
#18 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/app/Console/Commands/Fetcher.php(61): call_user_func('App\Revel\Entit...', Array)
#19 [internal function]: App\Console\Commands\Fetcher->handle()
#20 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(502): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(149): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#22 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(259): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(135): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(878): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(195): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\Console\Commands\Fetcher), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(126): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(98): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /var/www/myapp/htdocs/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#29 {main}
```

See how on line #2 the DB query in question is truncated with elipses? Is there any way to turn that off so I can see the entire query?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So I figured out my error, which was a missed protected cast, but I'd still like to know if there's a way to fix that truncation.

Comment: This is not Laravel specific, but rather PHP's stack trace.

Comment: Try increasing `zend.exception_ignore_args` option in your php.ini file.